# Can the extra players extension work with Seafearers or Cities and Knights?

Tags: catan

If I have the Settlers of Catan 5-6 player extension (for the base game), does that mean I can use the Seafarers or Cities and Knights expansions with 5-6 players?

Answer (score 11):

Seafarers and Cities & Knights have their own 5-6 Player expansions in addition to the base game 5-6 player expansion. Think of them as expansions to expansions. So to play a 6 player game of Seafarers you will need the following:

Base Catan Game + 5-6 Person Base Expansion + 4 player Seafarers Expansion + 5-6 Person Seafarers Expansion

Answer (score 9):

No--not easily at least. Each expansion has it's own 5-6 Player Extension, which you would need in addition to the base 5-6 Player extension. (BTW, they use the term *expansion* for things like Cities & Knights or Seafarers that change the rules significantly, and the term *extension* for sets that just add support for additional players.)

Seafarers adds boat pieces for each of the 4 base-set colors, but does not include boat pieces for the 2 additional colors. These you could proxy, or you could buy the Seafarers 5-6 Player Expansion.

Cities & Knights has more player-specific equipment: knights tokens, city walls, flipbooks for each player... playing without the C&K 5-6 Player extension would be very difficult. Traders & Barbarians is even more extreme than Cities & Knights.

Searching for the Expansion-Specific 5-6 Player Extensions on Boardgame Geek (Seafarers [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/4103/catan-seafarers-5-6-player-extension) and Cities & Knights [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/4101/catan-cities-knights-5-6-player-extension), Traders & Barbarians [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/34691/catan-traders-barbarians-5-6-player-extension)), you can see what they include.